# Converting a time machine backup to a clone

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, time-machine, clone

I'm having trouble memorizing some old passwords for some old protected DMG's. I'm hoping to find them in my old backups, because stupid young me probably saved them in his keychain (which doesn't fit the purpose of an encrypted DMG, I know, but it quite comes in handy now).

These backups are on a time machine disk. Is it possible to extract this time machine backup to a different harddisk than my main disk which contains my OS, so I can boot from this different hard disk (and view my old keychain) ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you just backup the current keychain and restore the file from a previous point.  You can then at that point extract the information you required, and then restore, the current keychain back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install a fresh copy of OSX on the external HDD. Boot the computer from it, then when wizard appears just follow on-screen instructions.

Or use  Carbon Copy Cloner to clone your TM backup to the other drive.

Comment: I didn't think of the first solution. I'll probably do it that way. Thanks